# Is there a way to make Eclipse open a hyperlinked java file from another project from the same workspace

Tags: java, eclipse, logging, hyperlink

Let's say I have two projects in my workspace, foo and bar.

Now I have project foo open that happens to use some jar generated by project bar. Some logger ends up vomiting the following in console, creating a clickable hyperlink:

```
(Bar.java:1)
```

Bar.java belonging in project bar.

Now if I click the hyperlink, it wont open Bar.java, but Bar.class inside bar.jar and then complain about 1 not being a valid line number.

Is there any way to change this behaviour either by Eclipse configuration or outputting something different with the logger?

Fwiw I'm using Eclipse Luna on Linux Mint 17.1.

edit: also, bar.jar is located under foo/lib/bar.jar

Comment: Where is the 'bar.jar' coming from?

Comment: bar build script ends up copying it under foo/lib/bar.jar

Answer (score 0):

You jar file doesn't have source files, but just class files. That is why it will open only class file.
If for debugging purpose you want to see java file opened when clicking that hyperlink, you can add that project in source in next project's setup.

Comment: Yeah, but even if it had the sources, I would want to open Bar.java from project bar directly so that I can edit it.